# (SQL in C++)How can I insert into variable?

Tags: c++, sql, postgresql, insert

```
void Insert(PGconn *conn)
{
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
std::string sSQL; 
sSQL.append("insert into data (var,var2) values(i,121)");
}
```

I refer to   http://www.askyb.com/cpp/c-postgresql-example/ 
It cannot works.Who can help me?
I want to insert to poastgresql.
Linux Ubuntu 13.04 g++ compiler

Comment: Please improve your question concerning structure, formatting and details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really an SQL problem. You have written

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    std::string sSQL;
sSQL.append("insert into data (var,var2) values(i,121)");
```

but you probably want to write

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    std::string sSQL;
    sSQL.append("insert into data (var,var2) values(i,121)");
}
```

otherwise sSQL will go out of scope before the last line.

Comment: sorry,i didn't describe details.you can see my another question.

Comment: Well, that was the only problem I could see with your code, except that you don't really need to use insert() right after you create your std::string, but perhaps that's lesson 2. ;)

Comment: Now, if you had a postgresql question, you cannot simply link to a tutorial and state that "it doesn't work". What didn't work? Be specific!

Comment: Sorry, should be append() in stead of insert() in my first comment